# How to stop plumber server

Tags: r, plumber

I have created a server using `plumber`

How do I stop the server?

"my approach -: once i get to know that , i will put a command , if we press a key then it will stop"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to stop this server , after you create it ,

once you created press `esc` to stop , there is no method like `close` or `stop`

Comment: how do I kill it if I started it with 'nohup' ?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo /usr/sbin/fuser -k 5551/tcp` kills the server (on port 5551)

Answer (score 0):

To stop the plumber server:

list all docker running with docker ps

```
sudo docker ps
```

get the {ID} of the process you want to stop and run the command

```
sudo docker kill {ID}
```